# What is the sum of the series with terms 1/(2/(3/(4/(5/(6/...?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, summation, fractions, oeis

I wondered how continually compounding a fraction in the denominator would behave as the successive denominators increment. What I was doing was essentially:

$\dfrac 1 {\dfrac 2 {\dfrac 3 {\dfrac 4 {\dfrac 5 {\dfrac 6 {\dfrac 7 {\dfrac 8 {\dfrac 9 {\vdots}}}}}}}}}$

I noticed that the result oscillated between numbers that were above 1 and below 1, and I realized that the pattern was actually progressing with respect to adding two numbers, i.e. the series is 1/2, 1/(2/(3/4)), etc.

Following this trail it appears that the limit as the number of (pairs of) denominators we add approaches infinity, this number approaches zero, at least as far as I can tell.

Consulting OEIS ([A001147](https://oeis.org/A001147), [A000165](https://oeis.org/A000165)) resulted in my inspiration to find the limit of the infinite sum as we travel down the fraction, and I was able to create what I believe is the correct formula:

$\displaystyle S_\infty=\sum_{i=1}^\infty{\prod_{n=1}^i{\dfrac{2n-1}{2n}}}$

So, what I am wondering is,

1. what is the solution to this, assuming it converges?
2. how can I (properly) prove that the expression above is also equal to the expression below (I am confident it is)?

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty{\dfrac{1}{4^n} \binom{2n}n}$

Personally hoping it's convergent, since I believe the terms tend to zero.

Comment: It is highly unclear what do you want, whats the connection between the tower in the beginning and your formula?

Comment: Your first step should be to simplify the expression of the $(2n)$th and $(2n+1)$th terms by removing the parentheses. After that, look up "Wallis product." I believe you may be misusing the summation sign in the formula for $S_\infty$, if what you're looking for is the limit of the fraction.

Comment: $\frac1{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\asymp\frac1{\sqrt{n\pi}}$ as $n\to\infty$, so your series diverges.

Answer (score 1):

Consider
$$ S_p=\sum_{i=1}^p{\prod_{n=1}^i{\dfrac{2n-1}{2n}}}=\sum_{i=1}^p  \frac{\Gamma \left(i+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }\,\Gamma (i+1)}=\frac{2 \,\Gamma \left(p+\frac{3}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }\, \Gamma (p+1)}-1$$
Using Stirling approximation
$$S_p=-1+2\sqrt{\frac p \pi}\left(1+\frac{3}{8 p}-\frac{7}{128 p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)\right)$$
On the other hand
$$T_p=\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^p{\dfrac{1}{4^n} \binom{2n}n}=-1+2^{-2 p-1} (p+1) \binom{2p+2}{p+1}=\frac{2 \Gamma \left(p+\frac{3}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi } \Gamma (p+1)}-1$$